# Left factorisation in Parsing Expression Grammar

Tags: c++, parsing, ambiguity, peg

I’m trying to write a grammar for a language which allows the following expressions:

1. Function calls of the form `f args` (note: no parentheses!)
2. Addition (and more complex expressions but that’s not the point here) of the form `a + b`

For example:

```
f 42       => f(42)
42 + b     => (42 + b)
f 42 + b   => f(42 + b)
```

The grammar is unambiguous (every expression can be parsed in exactly one way) but I don’t know how to write this grammar as a PEG since both productions potentially start with the same token, `id`. This is my wrong PEG. How can I rewrite it to make it valid?

```
expression ::= call / addition

call ::= id addition*

addition ::= unary
           ( ('+' unary)
           / ('-' unary) )*

unary ::= primary
        / '(' ( ('+' unary)
              / ('-' unary)
              / expression)
          ')'

primary ::= number / id

number ::= [1-9]+

id ::= [a-z]+
```

Now, when this grammar tries to parse the input “`a + b`” it parses “`a`” as a function call with zero arguments and chokes on “`+ b`”.

I’ve uploaded a [C++ / Boost.Spirit.Qi implementation of the grammar](https://gist.github.com/2146139) in case anybody wants to play with it.

---

(Note that `unary` disambiguates unary operations and additions: In order to call a function with a negative number as an argument, you need to specify parentheses, e.g. `f (-1)`.)

Comment: Is PEG a requirement? There are other parsing algorithms which may handle this without massive grammar restructuring. I'm a huge fan of [Pratt parsers](http://journal.stuffwithstuff.com/2011/03/19/pratt-parsers-expression-parsing-made-easy/), which should handle this easily and are [reasonably efficent](http://effbot.org/zone/simple-top-down-parsing.htm#performance) too.

Comment: @delnan Since I’m using Boost.Qi, PEGs are a fixed requirement, yes.

Comment: @delnan By the way, if I was unconstrained by technology I’d use a precedence matrix. That would make it as easy as specifying all the operator precedences, and parsing is technically efficient but I’ve never seen a ready-made implementation of that, and never a mention outside the Dragon Book, and the algorithm pseudocode is hard to understand and I think it contains an error.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

As proposed in [chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/transcript/message/3022997#3022997) you could start out with something like:

```
expression = addition | simple;

addition = simple >>
    (  ('+' > expression)
     | ('-' > expression)
    );

simple = '(' > expression > ')' | call | unary | number;

call = id >> *expression;

unary = qi::char_("-+") > expression;

// terminals
id = qi::lexeme[+qi::char_("a-z")];
number = qi::double_;
```

Since then I implemented this in C++ with an AST presentation, so you can get a feel for how this grammar actually build the expression tree by pretty printing it.

> **All source code is on github: https://gist.github.com/2152518**
>
> There are two versions (scroll down to 'Alternative' to read more

---

Grammar:

```
template <typename Iterator>
struct mini_grammar : qi::grammar<Iterator, expression_t(), qi::space_type> 
{
    qi::rule<Iterator, std::string(),  qi::space_type> id;
    qi::rule<Iterator, expression_t(), qi::space_type> addition, expression, simple;
    qi::rule<Iterator, number_t(),     qi::space_type> number;
    qi::rule<Iterator, call_t(),       qi::space_type> call;
    qi::rule<Iterator, unary_t(),      qi::space_type> unary;

    mini_grammar() : mini_grammar::base_type(expression) 
    {
        expression = addition | simple;

        addition = simple [ qi::_val = qi::_1 ] >> 
           +(  
               (qi::char_("+-") > simple) [ phx::bind(&append_term, qi::_val, qi::_1, qi::_2) ] 
            );

        simple = '(' > expression > ')' | call | unary | number;

        call = id >> *expression;

        unary = qi::char_("-+") > expression;

        // terminals
        id = qi::lexeme[+qi::char_("a-z")];
        number = qi::double_;
    }
};
```

The corresponding AST structures are defined quick-and-dirty using the very powerful Boost Variant:

```
struct addition_t;
struct call_t;
struct unary_t;
typedef double number_t;

typedef boost::variant<
    number_t,
    boost::recursive_wrapper<call_t>,
    boost::recursive_wrapper<unary_t>,
    boost::recursive_wrapper<addition_t>
    > expression_t;

struct addition_t
{
    expression_t lhs;
    char binop;
    expression_t rhs;
};

struct call_t
{
    std::string id;
    std::vector<expression_t> args;
};

struct unary_t
{
    char unop;
    expression_t operand;
};

BOOST_FUSION_ADAPT_STRUCT(addition_t, (expression_t, lhs)(char,binop)(expression_t, rhs));
BOOST_FUSION_ADAPT_STRUCT(call_t,     (std::string, id)(std::vector<expression_t>, args));
BOOST_FUSION_ADAPT_STRUCT(unary_t,    (char, unop)(expression_t, operand));
```

In the full code, I've also overloaded operator<< for these structures.

---

### Full Demo

```
//#define BOOST_SPIRIT_DEBUG
#include <iostream>
#include <iterator>
#include <string>

#include <boost/spirit/include/qi.hpp>
#include <boost/spirit/include/phoenix.hpp>
#include <boost/fusion/adapted.hpp>
#include <boost/optional.hpp>

namespace qi = boost::spirit::qi;
namespace phx= boost::phoenix;

struct addition_t;
struct call_t;
struct unary_t;
typedef double number_t;

typedef boost::variant<
    number_t,
    boost::recursive_wrapper<call_t>,
    boost::recursive_wrapper<unary_t>,
    boost::recursive_wrapper<addition_t>
    > expression_t;

struct addition_t
{
    expression_t lhs;
    char binop;
    expression_t rhs;

    friend std::ostream& operator<<(std::ostream& os, const addition_t& a) 
        { return os << "(" << a.lhs << ' ' << a.binop << ' ' << a.rhs << ")"; }
};

struct call_t
{
    std::string id;
    std::vector<expression_t> args;

    friend std::ostream& operator<<(std::ostream& os, const call_t& a)
        { os << a.id << "("; for (auto& e : a.args) os << e << ", "; return os << ")"; }
};

struct unary_t
{
    char unop;
    expression_t operand;

    friend std::ostream& operator<<(std::ostream& os, const unary_t& a)
        { return os << "(" << a.unop << ' ' << a.operand << ")"; }
};

BOOST_FUSION_ADAPT_STRUCT(addition_t, (expression_t, lhs)(char,binop)(expression_t, rhs));
BOOST_FUSION_ADAPT_STRUCT(call_t,     (std::string, id)(std::vector<expression_t>, args));
BOOST_FUSION_ADAPT_STRUCT(unary_t,    (char, unop)(expression_t, operand));

void append_term(expression_t& lhs, char op, expression_t operand)
{
    lhs = addition_t { lhs, op, operand };
}

template <typename Iterator>
struct mini_grammar : qi::grammar<Iterator, expression_t(), qi::space_type> 
{
    qi::rule<Iterator, std::string(),  qi::space_type> id;
    qi::rule<Iterator, expression_t(), qi::space_type> addition, expression, simple;
    qi::rule<Iterator, number_t(),     qi::space_type> number;
    qi::rule<Iterator, call_t(),       qi::space_type> call;
    qi::rule<Iterator, unary_t(),      qi::space_type> unary;

    mini_grammar() : mini_grammar::base_type(expression) 
    {
        expression = addition | simple;

        addition = simple [ qi::_val = qi::_1 ] >> 
           +(  
               (qi::char_("+-") > simple) [ phx::bind(&append_term, qi::_val, qi::_1, qi::_2) ] 
            );

        simple = '(' > expression > ')' | call | unary | number;

        call = id >> *expression;

        unary = qi::char_("-+") > expression;

        // terminals
        id = qi::lexeme[+qi::char_("a-z")];
        number = qi::double_;

        BOOST_SPIRIT_DEBUG_NODE(expression);
        BOOST_SPIRIT_DEBUG_NODE(call);
        BOOST_SPIRIT_DEBUG_NODE(addition);
        BOOST_SPIRIT_DEBUG_NODE(simple);
        BOOST_SPIRIT_DEBUG_NODE(unary);
        BOOST_SPIRIT_DEBUG_NODE(id);
        BOOST_SPIRIT_DEBUG_NODE(number);
    }
};

std::string read_input(std::istream& stream) {
    return std::string(
        std::istreambuf_iterator<char>(stream),
        std::istreambuf_iterator<char>());
}

int main() {
    std::cin.unsetf(std::ios::skipws);
    std::string const code = read_input(std::cin);
    auto begin = code.begin();
    auto end = code.end();

    try {
        mini_grammar<decltype(end)> grammar;
        qi::space_type space;

        std::vector<expression_t> script;
        bool ok = qi::phrase_parse(begin, end, *(grammar > ';'), space, script);

        if (begin!=end)
            std::cerr << "Unparsed: '" << std::string(begin,end) << "'\n";

        std::cout << std::boolalpha << "Success: " << ok << "\n";

        if (ok)
        {
            for (auto& expr : script)
                std::cout << "AST: " << expr << '\n';
        }
    }
    catch (qi::expectation_failure<decltype(end)> const& ex) {
        std::cout << "Failure; parsing stopped after \""
                  << std::string(ex.first, ex.last) << "\"\n";
    }
}
```

### Alternative:

I have an alternative version that build `addition_t` iteratively instead of recursively, so to say:

```
struct term_t
{
    char binop;
    expression_t rhs;
};

struct addition_t
{
    expression_t lhs;
    std::vector<term_t> terms;
};
```

This removes the need to use Phoenix to build the expression:

```
    addition = simple >> +term;

    term = qi::char_("+-") > simple;
```